# Верстка в Less отображается только в режиме отладки через Webstorm

Tags: html, css, less

Если запускать `index.html` с подключёнными `styles.less` и `less.js` из проводника, то стили работают только в Firefox.

Вопрос вот в чём: если запускать код из Webstorm вот этими ярлыками справа, то стили работают во всех браузерах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключение стилей и скрипта Less в head:

```
<head>
    <title>Main</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.less">
    <script src="less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">-->
    <!--<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8ac7dfc590.js"></script>-->
    <meta name="area.size" content="width=1600px,height=4518px">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите компилировать с помощью js скрипта, то порядок должен быть другой - сначала подключаем скрипт, а потом файл less. 
Чисто по логике, сначала должен врубиться js, а потом подгрузиться less, чтобы первый его подхватил.

Но зачем Вам это, если Вы работаете с webstorm? Там есть прекрасный встроенный компилятор для less и всего прочего.  Как его настроить, есть много статей, например - https://mbaev.com/content/avtomaticeskaa-kompilacia-css-v-phpstorm
Пусть Вас не смущает, что это для  PhpStorm, настраивается одинаково.